# Send $_GET variable to PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a simple database where I can run a 1 click email with a PDF attached. Currently I'm running that with the TCPDF function but I want to be able to send data to the PDF script using AJAX.

If someone can reference to what I need to read up on I would be grateful as most examples I can find only include pulling data from text files

For example:

```
<a href="tcpdf/PDF/testPDF.php?firstname=Ralph&datetime=2014-07-10 09:15:00&email=ralph1234@yahoo.com" target="_blank">Send Invitation</a>
```

If it helps here is my mail code:

```
// random hash necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "Invitation.pdf";

// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

///////////HEADERS INFORMATION////////////
// main header (multipart mandatory) message
$headers  = "From: test<no_reply@test.com>".$eol;
$headers .= "Bcc: joe@test.com".$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;

// message
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;

// attachment
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "--".$separator."--";


//Email message
mail($emailto, $emailsubject, $emailbody, $headers);
```

Comment: What data do you want to send?

Comment: All I'm trying to do is essentially 'run' the hyperlink rather than navigate to the actual page

Comment: Here you are: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to perform a `GET` using AJAX.

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Don't follow the link
    $.get(this.href, function(response) {
        // Display response
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Wheres the best place to go to read up on how to expand on this?

Comment: @JosephGregory The jQuery documentation, I've added a link to it in the answer.